# how to enable resharper html + javascript support in .php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, visual-studio, resharper

I'm considering to buy "php tools for visual studio" but I noticed that resharper support for html is not there inside .php files and I can't seem to find anywhere how to enable this.

Does anyone have any idea of how to do this?

ps. I know phpstorm exists and I've downloaded it too, but this tool seems more for people that want to dive deeply in to php and I would like to utilize as much as I can of my visual studio knowledge and tfs etc since php is only a minor part of my development efforts...

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't really do this, because php files aren't html or js files. If you did do it (and you should be able to by associating the .php extension with the html editor in Visual Studio's own options dialog), then ReSharper wouldn't parse the files correctly, because it wouldn't understand php syntax.

Comment: thanks for the answer, was hoping for a response that allowed me to work with php files, but how can I not accept an answer from an offical jetbrains evangelist. This feature would have been nice though... not php support but having resharper recognize php files and support html and js for people like me. I build my software in .net but have a php licensing system (much more cost-friendly)

Comment: "Official" sounds good :) It would be nice, but sadly, it does require ReSharper to at the very least understand that php code blocks are not invalid html. It's the mixture of languages within the files that causes the problem.